# Files and Multithreading

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading

I need to read two files by using multiple threads and print the content of the files in the console.The user will enter the file paths and use the threads to read the contents of the files. I have a hard time understanding files. Can anyone just suggest me what should be done in the run method?

```
import java.io.*;

public class Ch3Ex4 implements Runnable
 {
  public void ReadFile(String str,Thread thread)
   {
    try
     {
      File inputFile = new File(str);
      FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
     }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  } 
    public void run()
      {

      } 

 public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    try
    {
    Ch3Ex4 obj = new Ch3Ex4();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter the two file paths:");
    String s1 = br.readLine();
    String s2 = br.readLine();
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(obj);
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(obj);
    obj.ReadFile(s1, thread1);
    obj.ReadFile(s2, thread2);
    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: What is the point of using threads to read file? It will not speed up the operation, which is I/O bound...

Comment: I am doing some exercises online for JAVA.This was asked in the question so I need to use threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `run` method is meant to contain the code which is executed by that thread. So, as you want to read two files from two different threads, you'll need to use `run` for doing whatever you're doing in `ReadFile` method.

Note that you'll need to create an instance of `Ch3Ex4` class and invoke the `start` method in order to start to start a new thread.

EDIT: In that case, you can use a `BufferedReader` inside the `run` method like this: (From [mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/)'s website)

```
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {

        String sCurrentLine;

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testing.txt"));

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah I have created the instance and invoked the start method.I am just trying to figure out the steps to read and print.

Comment: I've added that to my answer now.

Comment: But what does sCurrentLine hold here? It is just a declared string.

Comment: As you read the code below, `String` returned by `readLine()` method is assigned to `sCurrentLine`, which is then printed to the output console.

Comment: But still 1 more doubt...what about sending of the string?

Comment: Didn't get you. What do you mean by sending of the string?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned either you should move code in ReadFile into run method or alternatively call the ReadFile() method from within run(). In addition, you need to make an instance variable for file name and create two objects for two threads. 
See the changes highligted:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Ch3Ex4 implements Runnable
{
     String s1;

     Ch3Ex4(String s){
           s1=s;
     }

     public void ReadFile(String str){
       //existing code 
     } 

     public void run()
     {
        ReadFile(s1);
     } 

     public static void main (String[] args)
     {
        try
        {
           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
           System.out.println("Enter the two file paths:");
           String s1 = br.readLine();
           String s2 = br.readLine();
           Ch3Ex4 obj1 = new Ch3Ex4(s1);
           Ch3Ex4 obj2 = new Ch3Ex4(s2);

           Thread thread1 = new Thread(obj1);
           Thread thread2 = new Thread(obj2);

           thread1.start();
           thread2.start();
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope below code is what you looking.

```
 public class Ch3Ex4 implements Runnable
 {
    String file;
    public void Ch3Ex4 (String file)
    {
       this.file = file;
    } 
    public void run()
    {
    try
       {
        File inputFile = new File(file);
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        int data;
        while((data = in.read()) != null){
                System.out.println(data);
           }
       }
       catch(Exception e)
      {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  } 

   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
    try
       {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter the two file paths:");
        String s1 = br.readLine();
        String s2 = br.readLine();
        Ch3Ex4 thread1 = new Ch3Ex4(s1);
        Ch3Ex4 thread2 = new Ch3Ex4(s2);
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
  }
```